# What is the name of equipment that is used in films, like when saying "scene one, take two"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

What is the name of equipment that is used in films, like when saying "scene one, take two"?
The equipment is usually black and white in color.

Answer (score 12):

[*Clapperboard*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapperboard). Though I've been told that in the US it is much more commonly known as *slate*.

> Other names for the clapperboard include *clapper*, *clapboard*, *slate*, *slate board*, *sync slate*, *time slate*, *sticks*, *board*, and *marker*.

Comment: Bonus points for the picture of a clapperboard used in a black and white movie.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: [voilà](http://www.google.de/images?q=hitchcock+psycho+clapperboard)!